# Randomizing colours of each recursion

Tags: python, colors, python-turtle

I have a working fractal H tree here that randomizes the color in terms of the whole tree at once being a randomized color.

However, I wanted to try and get each individual fractal (each recursion) to be a random color. I am not sure how to do this and have tried to find solutions but have come up short.

I am kinda new to some of this stuff so sorry if this is a silly problem

```
import turtle
import time
import random


SPEED = 10
BG_COLOR = "white"
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
DRAWING_WIDTH = 700
DRAWING_HEIGHT = 700
PEN_WIDTH = 4
TITLE = "Fractal H tree"
FRACTAL_DEPTH = 3

color = [random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)]



def draw_line(tur, pos1, pos2):
    # print("Drawing from", pos1, "to", pos2)
    tur.penup()
    tur.goto(pos1[0], pos1[1])
    tur.pendown()
    tur.goto(pos2[0], pos2[1])

def recursive_draw(tur, x, y, width, height, count):

    time.sleep(0.5)
    draw_line(tur, [x + width * 0.25, height // 2 + y],[x + width * 0.75, height // 2 + y],)
    draw_line(tur,[x + width * 0.25, (height * 0.5) // 2 + y],[x + width * 0.25, (height * 1.5) // 2 + y],)
    draw_line(tur,[x + width * 0.75, (height * 0.5) // 2 + y],[x + width * 0.75, (height * 1.5) // 2 + y],)

    if count <= 0:
        return
    else:  # The recursive part
        count -= 1
        # Top left
        recursive_draw(tur, x, y, width // 2, height // 2, count)
        # Top right
        recursive_draw(tur, x + width // 2, y, width // 2, height // 2, count)
        # Bottom left
        recursive_draw(tur, x, y + width // 2, width // 2, height // 2, count)
        # Bottom right
        recursive_draw(tur, x + width // 2, y + width // 2, width // 2, height // 2, count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Screen setup
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    screen.title(TITLE)
    screen.bgcolor(BG_COLOR)
    screen.colormode(255)

    # Turtle (pen) setup
    tur = turtle.Turtle()
    tur.hideturtle()
    tur.pencolor(color)
    tur.pensize(PEN_WIDTH)
    tur.speed(SPEED)

    # Initial call to recursive draw function
    recursive_draw(tur, - DRAWING_WIDTH / 2, - DRAWING_HEIGHT / 2, DRAWING_WIDTH, DRAWING_HEIGHT, FRACTAL_DEPTH)

    turtle.done()
```

Comment: Put `tur.pencolor([random.randint(0,255) for _ in range(3)])` inside your `recursive_draw` function.

Comment: @Samwise thank you so much just tried it and it worked. much appreciated

Comment: Or put it inside `draw_line` if you want each individual line to be its own color instead of each H!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Samwise says just set your pen color inside recursive draw.